# System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid. : '\\?\C:\\XXX\\XXX, while trying to delete a file, and the file type is "DirectoryInfo"

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

For one of my **web development** activity using **.Netcore Api 3.1**
I have to upload a file and do certain operation if the file is not in right format delete it.
I have uploaded the file using  IForm File and stored in a temp folder by using GetRandomFileName,
`randaomPathtoSave = Path.Combine(Path.GetRandomFileName(), "upload");`
and passing the file to a function using a file Type of "DirectoryInfo", for wrong format file in the function trying to delete using **file.Delete();** , however its throwing an exception "System.IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid. : '\?\C:\XXX\XXXX" ,

```
        public void check(DirectoryInfo file)
    {
        if (isFileFormatisCorrect)
        {
            //do certain operations
        }
        else
        {
            file.Delete();
        }

    }
```

I could see clearly that the path contains some invalid characters **\?** appended at starting of string path , I have no idea how these special characters had been added.

I even tried to delete by using

```
Directory.Delete(resultPath, true);
```

by converting File type to path , but still the issue persists.

**Note: FYI. You might have a question. Why do really need to upload the file if it is in wrong format at first place.
I have a project requirement to store and check , not check and store**

Comment: See [Win32 File Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces).

Comment: Can you please show how you create the `DirectoryInfo` that you are passing to the `check()` method?